# What components would be in a general cutting spell?

Tags: spells, spell-components, ars-magica-5

The spell I have in mind is extremely similar to 'diffindo' in Harry Potter. The user gestures across a path a short distance away, and as if by an invisible knife, a minor linear cut is made across the path.

The material of the object could be a multitude of things, such as fabric, or chalk, or flesh, but in all cases it is a small cut.

What components would be in this spell? And how difficult would it be to cast?

I'm unsure whether it would be considered Perdo or Muto, as well as how to classify the broad range of materials that the spell would be able to cut.

Comment: What is the intended effect against living targets?

Comment: @goodguy5 Ideally a minute but non-zero amount of damage

Comment: In RPG contexts, "spell components" normally refers to physical objects used to cast a spell, and usually consumed in the process, rather than characteristics of the spell itself (magnitude, range, etc.). To avoid confusion, you may want to edit your question to not mention "components".

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a Perdo spell. As ArsMagica considers the substance being affected in the spell design, so there is not one spell written up which covers this in the books. You will need to look at the guidelines for each Form using Perdo, and then add an additional magnitude for each additional form. 
e.g. PeAq base 10 for liquids, Base 4 for Air, base 5 to inflict a Light wound to a beast, etc.

Say a base of 10, then +1 mag for another 5 Arts is +5 mags, then range Voice is +2, then to affect Part of the thing is +1. Becomes PeAq/AnAuCoHeTe level 50. And that won't affect metals or stone, just dirt.

It will become a extremely high level spell, and not worth it. Separate spells for each Form are so much better; one for PeTe, etc.

Another approach is to use magic to move something to make the cuts, like moving a blade using Rego. That will allow a single Form+Tech combination to move the blade, which will affect many things, but obviously not all things.
e.g. a metal blade is good against human bodies and animals, but probably ineffective against stone pathways and wooden doors.

Comment: A spell to create a spinning blade might work best, like a magical angle grinder or magical meat slicer.

Comment: Only corpus, herbem, animal and terram are necessary. Plus, it’s a very thin line.

Comment: Even with one primary art and 3 requisites its still going to be around level 35. eg. say PeCo5, +3 Reqs, +2 Voice, +1 Part = PeCo/HeAnTe35. That spell will also be very difficult to create in the lab because of the higher level and all the reqs. Say it takes 5-6 seasons of work for an experienced Perdo magus to create it - that wizard is far better off using a much smaller PeCo20 spell, and having three others up his sleeve.

Comment: And a high level spell is far worse if the target has Parma or MR.